# C# Json serialization: Multiple variables as array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am experimenting with the Newtonsoft.Json serializer and I am wondering if it would be possible to say that multiple variables of a class are put inside in an array instead of seperate values.
For example, take a Vector3 struct with 3 floats: x, y and z.

```
public class myVector3
{
   public float X, Y, Z;
}
```

Can you make that it looks like this: 
`"myVector3": [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]`

instead of

```
"myVector3": {
        "X": 0.0,
        "Y": 0.0,
        "Z": 0.0
      }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GeoffJames: That's simply not true - the request JSON is entirely valid. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-5

Comment: @GeoffJames `{ "myVector3": [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] }` is perfectly valid JSON - deserialising it to a class like that would be unconventional but is ultimately the choice of the application. Personally if I had that JSON structure and that class I would use an intermediary class with a `public decimal[] myVector3` property.

Comment: Noted, thank you guys - I jumped the gun like a numpty when I read the question -- comment deleted *more coffee required...*

Answer (score 0):

My research into this yielded the following:

You would need your own custom `JsonConverter` to pull out the `X, Y, Z` values of your vector and turn them into some kind of float array:

```
public class VectorSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.FromObject(value);
        var x = token["X"].Value<float>();
        var y = token["Y"].Value<float>();
        var z = token["Z"].Value<float>();
        var vector = new[] { x, y, z };
        var o = JArray.FromObject(vector);
        o.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var item = JObject.Load(reader);
        var vector = item["myVector3"].ToObject<float[]>();
        return new myVector3 { X = vector[0], Y = vector[1], Z = vector[2] };
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(myVector3).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
public class myVector3
{
    public float X, Y, Z;
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
        var vectorFromString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myVector3>("{\"myVector3\": [1.0, 1.5, 2.5]}", new VectorSerializer());
        //You'll get your vector object from this string ^
        var vectorToString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vectorFromString, new VectorSerializer());
        //Output: "[1.0, 1.5, 2.5]"
```

Answer (score -3):

No, it needs to contain key and value. Check here [json](http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/structures.php)